# $0\le d(x_n, a)<\frac{1}{n}\implies \lim x_n = a$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, metric-spaces

I need to prove the following:

$$0\le d(x_n, a)<\frac{1}{n}\implies \lim x_n = a$$

It looks pretty intuitive since I can make $\frac{1}{n}$ as small as I want, thusk making $a$ as close as to $x_n$ as I want.

I need to come with this:

$$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists n_0\in \mathbb{N} | n>n_o\implies d(x_n,a)<\epsilon$$

My idea was the following: given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that:

$$d(x_n,a)<\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$$

I could just choose $n_0 = \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ and I'd have:

$$n> n_0\implies n>\frac{1}{\epsilon}\implies \frac{1}{n}<\epsilon\implies d(x_n,a) <\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$$

Also, do you think that this exercise is somehow linked with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1795855/questions-about-proof-of-lim-x-n-a-lim-y-n-b-implies-lim-x-ny-n-ab)? It comes right after these exercises and the $\frac{1}{n}$ makes me think that there is a way to do it using that theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $n_0\in\mathbb N$, you can't choose $n_0=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$. What you can choose is $n_0=\lfloor\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\rfloor +1$. But you don't need to explicit the $n_0$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{1}{n}=0,$$
there is a $n_0\in\mathbb N$ s.t. $\frac{1}{n}<\varepsilon$ when $n\geq n_0$. Therefore, if $n\geq n_0$, $$d(a,x_n)<\frac{1}{n}<\varepsilon,$$
and in particular $d(a,x_n)<\varepsilon$ if $n\geq n_0$ what prove the claim.

Answer (score 2):

So this doesn't quite work but you are definitely on the right track. The only problem with your argument is that we don't know *a priori* that $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ is a natural number. However, try repeating your argument with any natural number $k$ such that $k<\frac{1}{\epsilon}$. This will solve the problem, because given $\epsilon>0$, we have $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$ d(x_k,a)<\frac{1}{k}<\epsilon$$
as desired.